# Basic SQL syntax SELECT [number]

Tags: sql, select, sapb1

I'm working with SAP Business One in a formatted search and have run into some syntax I am unfamiliar with or haven't come across before. This is probably pretty basic but can anybody shed some light on this please?

Ignore the $[system objects].

```
DECLARE @parent nVarChar(15)
SET @parent = (SELECT T0.FNum
FROM OACT T0
WHERE T0.ACode = $[DLN1.ACode])
```

> ```
>   @parent ='40099'
> ```

```
begin
    if $[OCRD.ctry] = 'UK' and $[OCRD.zip] not like 'BBT_%%' begin select 19 end
    else if $[ocrd.country] = 'SA' or $[ocrd.zipcode] like 'BBT_%%' begin select 31 end
    else if $[ocrd.country] = 'NZ' begin select 41 end
    else if $[ocrd.country] = 'AUS' begin select 51 end
    else select 21
end
```

The full query currently doesn't work, but my question is, typically what does the "Select 21" or "Select 41" or "Select 51"  or select xxx number return? Can anybody provide an example which will help me understand?

Thanks

Comment: did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select [VALUE] will return just a value.

**Oracle:**

```
select 'Hello' from Dual
```

**SQL Server:**

```
Select 'Hello'
```

So what your code seems to be doing is setting/displaying a value, nothing more.

An example of another way you can use it, multiple items within a select:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/28218/0

This works both in SQL Server and Oracle, no need for Dual.

Answer (score 0):

`Select XX` will return `XX`.

For Example I've three rows in my table bookings and I do `select 21 from tablename` then I'll get the following result

[image]

and if i just do `select 21` , it will give me this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is simply selecting a literal value, in this case, a number. So if this code is within a function or stored procedure then it would return one of those numbers. Here is an example of setting a variable using a similar syntax:

```
DECLARE @NUMBER INT
SET @NUMBER = (SELECT 41)
-- above is identical to:
SET @NUMBER = 41
```

It is no different to any SELECT statement except that we are more familiar with a SELECT statement returning data from tables rather than an explicitly defined literal value as it is in your code.

I hope that answers your question but please don't hesitate to ask for more clarification.